# Show values from GLOBAL STATUS

Tags: mysql

I run this command in MySQL

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
```

How I can get only 3 values from the long list of results?

Can I get some result using SQL query?

I tested this:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS where variable_name='Bytes_received' and variable_name='Bytes_sent';
```

Comment: Which 3 values? You could use `WHERE`.

Comment: Something like this: `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS where variable_name='Bytes_received' and variable_name='Bytes_sent';`

Answer (score 3):

Try using `IN`

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS where variable_name IN ('Bytes_received','Bytes_sent');
```

Or you could use `OR`

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS WHERE variable_name='Bytes_received' or variable_name='Bytes_sent';
```

If you want to show them as columns (e.g.

```
Bytes Received | Bytes Sent
123445         | 7654667
```

You could try something like:

```
SELECT 
    a.variable_value AS 'Bytes_received',
    b.variable_value AS 'Bytes_sent'
FROM 
    information_schema.global_status a, 
    information_schema.global_status b
where 
    a.variable_name = 'Bytes_received'
and
    b.variable_name = 'Bytes_sent'
```

It's not very pretty though, and not really practical for a lot of results. (and of course it doesn't work in 5.7 as the information_schema tables are disabled by default)

Comment: How I can display the result as columns?

Comment: I've added an option above that may help?

Comment: Is there other way to get this data?

Comment: If you do a Google search for something like 'mysql transpose or pivot or unpivot' you will find various options most of which involve `UNION` queries. Really it depends on how many rows/columns you are looking at?